# Side-effects in JetPack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, side-effects

While I understand or think I understand, what side-effects are in jet-pack compose.

```
It's any work done in composable which escapes the scope of the composable function
```

I understand doing stuff like I/O operations or mutating a variable outside of function scope, giving reference and not clearing it (memory leak), or mutating a local variable that is not composable state - these all are side-effects, as they can lead to unexpected behavior and leaks because of recomposition, which is not deterministic and can run many times. And to take care of side-effects, we have effect-handlers.

Considering everything above, I need a bit of clarity in a few scenarios

- Side-effect - in case of mutating object, does it holds true for any object other than compose object? As in compose states (mutableStateOf etc..) doesn't lead to side-effects? Why?
- Why callbacks/state/event hoisting to your activity/fragment/viewmodel,does not lead to side-effect?

**For example**

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
viewModel:MyViewModel,
launchSomeActivity:()->Unit
){
   var state by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   state = "some string" // not a side-effect?

   viewModel.someStringObject = "a" // it's a side-effect?

   launchSomeActivity() // it's a side-effect?

   when(val screenState = viewModel.screenState.collectAsState().value){
      is ScreenState.Success -> launchSomeActivity() // not a side-effect. why?
      is ScreenState.Error -> state="some String" // not a side-effect. why?
   }
}
```

---

I also recall reading somewhere, trigger side-effects from callbacks, such as `onClick` as that always executes on UI thread, or say calling some lambda from ViewModel.

Would like to understand the above scenario as well, as in how it prevents side-effects, calling a lambda or a callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SideEffect` doesn't imply that anything else isn't a side-effect.  It is an escape-hatch for things should be considered and effect of composition but are not, or cannot be, expressed in the node tree.

For example, `Dialog` uses `SideEffect` to communicated dialog properties, layout-direction and the dismiss callback from the `Dialog` parameters to the Android dialog created as a result of composition. This presents the illusion that `Dialog` is natively part of Compose even though it uses the view system to create the dialog.

In general, a composition function should only read state, not modify state. If it does modify state it should be only to state created during composition and used by the composable functions called directly by the composable function that created the state; and only before any of the children read the state, and not after.

> Side-effect - in case of mutating object, does it holds true for any object other than compose object? As in compose states (mutableStateOf etc..) doesn't lead to side-effects? Why?

Composable functions should only read the state in these objects; it should not be modifying this state. For observable state, such as `mutableStateOf`, Compose observes changes to this state and will schedule a recomposition of the composable functions that read the state. You can use `mutableStateOf` to perform side-effects; you shouldn't.

> Why callbacks/state/event hoisting to your activity/fragment/viewmodel,does not lead to side-effect?

Not if they are used correctly, no; not from Compose's perspective. Composition functions are a transform function from the data they read to user interface tree. As the view model changes, the transform is incrementally re-evaluated to produce the UI implied by the new state of the view model. State hoisting allows higher-level parts of the application that have more context over how the data should be stored and/or validated, to control the state of lower-level, more generic parts of the application. The components that have hoisted state should never write to the state. If they need to state to be changed they should call an event handler with the new desired state or with a description of what change to make (e.g. `DeleteCustomer #1234`). It should be up to the provided event handlers to actually make the change to the hoisted state.

> `state = "some string" // not a side-effect?`

No, it is not. It initializes `state` as state does not escape the composition is considered part of the composition. This is not recommended practice but it is not a side-effect.

> `launchSomeActivity()`

This is a side-effect and should be performed in `LaunchEffect` which will launch the co-routine in a scope that will automatically be cancelled when the composition function is no longer called in the composition.

> `is ScreenState.Success -> launchSomeActivity() // not a side-effect. why?`

This is a side effect for the same reason with the same answer.

> `is ScreenState.Error -> state="some String" // not a side-effect. why?`

This is not a side-effect as mentioned above (i.e. a side-effect implies it has an effect to something outside of composition, this doesn't), but, if `state` has already been read then it is considered a backwards write and heavily discouraged as it could cause composition to be repeated, perhaps indefinitely; as anything that has already read it might be rescheduled to be executed again.

Comment: I'm a but confused by the `SideEffect` in Compose. AFAIR this is the way to make side effects legal from the POV of compose. What I don't understand is what might be the consequences of not using it? For instance, this example https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#sideeffect-publish - nothing seems to change if we simply call `analytics.valye.setUserProperty` from within the composable itself.

Comment: or speaking about your example with `Dialog`: what would change if we updated `Dialog` parameters right from within the composition, instead of wrapping update into `SideEffect`? I mean, besides of obvious things, like execution after `applier` and execution only if composition succeeds.

Comment: The key words in the comment for the example are "successful composition". A composition is not guaranteed to be successful and the order it executes is not guaranteed. `SideEffect` will only be called when the composition succeeds and and will execute in a reasonable order (`SideEffect`s called before child compositions are executed before the children and `SideEffect`s called after child compositions execute after the children's `SideEffect`s, for example).